# Class from PHAR not found

Tags: php, phar, nette-tester

I want to use the PHAR from nette-tester V1.7.1 ... and build a simple script that runs a test, but i fail at a very basic level.

The class Tester\Runner\CliTester is correct and available within the PHAR, but is not found.

Composer is no option and including all files without the phar would we the worst option.

Input:

```
<?php 
include_once 'tester.phar';
$tester = new Tester\Runner\CliTester;
die($tester->run());
```

Output:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Tester\Runner\CliTester' not found in 
C:\webdev\testrunner.php on line 14 Call Stack: 0.0000 136168 1. {main}() 
C:\webdev\testrunner.php:0
```

Comment: i have the same error XD

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply run CliTester you just need to run `php tester.php` in your command line.

If you include `tester.phar` into your application some files are not loaded. Look at `stub.php` in `tester.phar`.